# What is the difference between rdp files?

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, rdp, remoteapp

When remotely connecting to my server using Windows' **Remote Desktop Connection** application, I can save Connection settings in an RDP file and then easily edit it right clicking and selecting "edit".

Also I can create an RDP file for a RemoteApp program in a RemoteApp Manager of my server. But it is impossible to edit the settings of the RDP file in the way as for the RDP file created from **Remote Desktop Connection** application.

Why is that? What is difference between these two types of RDP files and what is the difference between these two types of remote desktop sessions? Is there any way to change the IP address of the Computer parameter of the RDP file, created from a RemoteApp Manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDP files are (or at least used to be) plain text files. Try opening one in Notepad or your favourite text editor.

Comment: Thanks! Your info is really helpful. I easily opened both files with Notepad and so was able to edit any parameter. Additionally, I can see all parameters, RDP file consists of, and google them. +1